# JBoss 4.2 Autodiscovery Failure (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: linux, performance, redhat, performance-monitoring, jboss

I am experimenting with Hyperic for the first time. I have a basic server & agent setup and working on a Redhat Linux box. But when the autodiscoverer is running for JBoss 4.2 I get the exceptions at the end of this message.

I configured the `jboss.installpath` setting in the `agent.properties`. And when I start the agent with `DEBUG` level logging I see the various JBoss jars being included from my configured path. But I can not autodiscover JBoss, I continue to get the same exceptions. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated...

```
011-06-17 14:25:27,572 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Running runtime autodiscovery for NetworkServer
2011-06-17 14:25:27,582 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] NetworkServer discovery took 0
2011-06-17 14:25:27,582 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Running runtime autodiscovery for JBoss 4.2
2011-06-17 14:25:27,941 ERROR [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Unable to run autodiscoverer for plugin: JBoss 4.2 (consult product setup help): null
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.invocation.MarshalledInvocation.<clinit>(MarshalledInvocation.java:68)
        at org.jboss.invocation.jrmp.interfaces.JRMPInvokerProxy.invoke(JRMPInvokerProxy.java:120)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invokeInvoker(InvokerInterceptor.java:365)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InvokerInterceptor.invoke(InvokerInterceptor.java:197)
        at org.jboss.jmx.connector.invoker.client.InvokerAdaptorClientInterceptor.invoke(InvokerAdaptorClientInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.jboss.proxy.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ClientMethodInterceptor.invoke(ClientMethodInterceptor.java:74)
        at org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer.invoke(ClientContainer.java:100)
        at $Proxy1.queryNames(Unknown Source)
        at org.hyperic.hq.plugin.jboss.JBossDetector.discoverServiceTypes(JBossDetector.java:368)
        at org.hyperic.hq.product.ServerDetector.discoverResources(ServerDetector.java:209)
        at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.agent.server.RuntimeAutodiscoverer.doRuntimeScan_internal(RuntimeAutodiscoverer.java:272)
        at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.agent.server.RuntimeAutodiscoverer.doRuntimeScan(RuntimeAutodiscoverer.java:205)
        at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.ScanManager.mainRunLoop(ScanManager.java:165)
        at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.ScanManager.access$000(ScanManager.java:41)
        at org.hyperic.hq.autoinventory.ScanManager$1.run(ScanManager.java:107)
2011-06-17 14:25:27,943 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Running runtime autodiscovery for Net Services
2011-06-17 14:25:27,953 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Net Services discovery took 0
2011-06-17 14:25:27,953 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Running runtime autodiscovery for HQ Agent
2011-06-17 14:25:27,962 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] HQ Agent discovery took 0
2011-06-17 14:25:27,962 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] Running runtime autodiscovery for FileServer
2011-06-17 14:25:27,969 INFO  [Thread-2] [RuntimeAutodiscoverer] FileServer discovery took 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the jbossall-client.jar from JBoss in the classpath of Hyperic Agent i.e. (in the relevant lib of Hyperice Agent).

Also check..

The problem can be due to the Hyperic-Agent couln't catch the JBoss-Server because the used backslashes instead of ordinary slashes.

jboss.installpath=e:\jboss-4.2.1.GA -> NOT OK

jboss.installpath=e:/jboss-4.2.1.GA -> OK